# Loader content cannot be displayed in custom resolution

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a custom full screen mode for my media player. It basically assigns content to resized movie clip and displays. However when comes to particular contents it is unable to show in full screen mode. Actually there is no problem in default but only in FS. Here is the code that activates FS Mode.

```
function FSMode(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    fullScreenToolbar = new ExitFSClass();//this exits full screen
    _coordinate.x = contentLdr.content.x;
    _coordinate.y = contentLdr.content.y;
    _width = contentLdr.content.width;
    _height = contentLdr.content.height;
    contentLdr.content.x = -250;
    contentLdr.content.y = -135;
    this.setChildIndex(contentLdr, this.numChildren - 1);
    if(contentTypArr[currentCategory] === "animation")
    {
        addChild(fullScreenToolbar);
        this.setChildIndex(fullScreenToolbar, this.numChildren - 1);
        if(Capabilities.screenResolutionX >= 1920)
        {
            contentLdr.content.width = 1800;
            contentLdr.content.height = 1012.5;
        }
        else
        {
            contentLdr.content.width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
            contentLdr.content.height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
        }
        fullScreenToolbar.x = 0;
        fullScreenToolbar.y = 965;
        fullScreenToolbar.width = contentLdr.content.width;
        fullScreenToolbar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openToolbar);
        fullScreenToolbar.buttonMode = true;
    }
}
```

Why some contents cannot be displayed? I am unable to see related problem or conflict with code.

Comment: Don't talk about fullscreen when you don't use fullscreen. Describe more precisely the problem and ask a question. Why use 'setChildIndex(fullScreenToolbar, this.numChildren - 1)' all over the place when a simple addChild() does the same?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe `addChild` doesn't work? And this is the only way I can handle? Also if the content is displayed in full screen(literally), it is full screen, full stop(literally).

Comment: In order to get help here you do understand that anything you say must be clear and comprehensible right? Now since there's such a thing as Fullscreen mode in AS3 and you are here implementing an unrelated  'custom' fullscreen don't you think this should be made clear at all time in your question? If you don't no big deal you just likely won't get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the `Loader` content resolution is different (greater in this situation) than the displaying area. There are overflowing parts that makes `fs` not working properly. Fixing the content resolution makes no problem and the function operates well.